# Predict if a number is odd or even using Logistic Regression formula y = x % 2 + 0

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Given array of numbers from 1-20 (X_train) and array of binary values from 0 or 1 (y_train) passing it to Logistic Regression algorithm and then training the model. Trying to predict with below X_test gives me incorrect data.

Created the sample train and test data as shown below. Please suggest what's wrong with the code.

```
import numpy as np

X_train = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], dtype=float).reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0], dtype=float)
X_test = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 55, 88, 99, 100], dtype=float).reshape(-1, 1)

from sklearn import linear_model
logreg = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predict = logreg.predict(X_test)
print(y_predict)

Output :
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Comment: Where is the formula `y = x % 2 + 0` in your code?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code - please read up on what [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) is. It might help to think in terms of linear regression to start with - you are trying to fit a straight line through alternating 1's and 0's - and linear regression will come up with a flat line as the best fit, or a slope that does not mean much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question was already asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161189/train-a-neural-network-to-distinguish-between-even-and-odd-numbers). I would like to use this post as inspiration for my solution.

But first let me mention two things:

1. A logistic regression is very beneficial in terms of time, performance and explainability if you have some kind of nested-linear relationships between your feature(s) and label, but obviously that is not the case for your example. You want to estimate a discontinous function that equals one if your input is odd and zero otherwise, which is not easily achieved.
2. Your data representation is not good. I think this point is more critical for your prediction goal as a better data representation does lead to a better prediction.

Next, I would like to share an alternative data representation. This new representation does yield perfect prediction results, even for a simple untuned logistic regression.

Code:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

X_train = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20])
y_train = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0], dtype=float)
X_test = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 55, 88, 99, 100])

def convert_repr(x):
    return list(map(int, list(str(format(x, '016b')))))

# Change data representation
X_train = np.array(list(map(convert_repr, X_train)))
X_test = np.array(list(map(convert_repr, X_test)))

logreg = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predict = logreg.predict(X_test)
print(y_predict)
```

Output:

```py
[1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
```

As you can see, the data is more important than the actual model.

Comment: You are converting numbers to binary and use binaries for classification. Kinds of cheating! you're putting the target in the features! It's not learning anything! If the last digit of a binary number is 1, the number is odd; if it's 0, the number is even!

Comment: Always doubt when you get 100% accuracy in classification!

Comment: @bpfrd, true. The `lr` model is using the last feature to achieve this perfect prediction. Perhaps I was not clear enough, the post was not about convincing that this representation is the best, I just wanted to highlight that data representation is - in my opinion - at least as crucial as the model itself. Even so, when replacing the last feature that contains the label by - for instance - the cumulative sum of it, it still achieves a 71% accuracy. The representation suggested by W. Gottschalk in the mentioned post (see link) would be better suited. One can just get creative..

Answer (score 2):

It is an ill-posed task: for logistic regression to work, there should be some point on the x axis which separates the high probability region from the low probability region of the target class (as you see in the test output). With alternating even/odd outputs, this can obviously not be a correct model, thus learning is completely instable.

You either need better features, or a more complex model with can take care of the more complicated space.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your code is wrong. Your model is too simple to learn such a complex non-linear behaviour. If you use a decision tree which is more flexible instead it can learn the **training data** better:

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import graphviz 
import numpy as np

X_train = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], dtype=float).reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0], dtype=float)
X_test = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 55, 88, 99, 100], dtype=float).reshape(-1, 1)
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predict = clf.predict(X_test)
print(y_predict)
```

Output:

```
[1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

You can also visualize the tree with:

```
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None) 
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data) 
graph.render("Odd-Even")
```

It will generate a pdf file of the tree. For this you need to install `graphviz` by `pip install graphviz`

Comment: The DT was only able to predict those values correctly, that already are included in the training data.. I think the data representation is at least as important as the model.

Comment: I know. But atleast it could learn the train set. Some models can not even do that.